# Is analytical solution available for this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I been trying to solve the below PDE analytically for awhile now but with no success, perhaps someone here can help me with it.
$$
\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \bigg(\beta \exp (-g(x)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big\{ w(x,t) \exp(g(x)) \big\} \bigg)
$$

And the boundary and initial conditions:  (1) $$ w(x,0)=m $$ and (2) $$w(0,t)=n, w(L,t)=p$$.

Is analytical solution possible here?

Comment: Are $m$, $n$, and $p$ numbers or functions?

Comment: They are constants

Comment: This is the one-dimensional heat equation with Dirichlet conditions, right?

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer, in principle Yes!

Answer (score 0):

If you write $w(x,t) = v(x,t) \exp(-g(t))$, the PDE becomes

$$ \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \beta\dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} - \beta g'(x) \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$
This has separation-of-variables solutions
$v(x,t) = X(x) T(t)$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant and
$$ T'(t) =  c \beta T(t), \ X''(x) =  c X(x) + g'(x) X'(x) $$
In general I think the equation for $X$ can't be solved in closed form, but can be reduced to a first-order nonlinear equation: if $X(x) = \exp(u(x))$,
$u'' + (u')^2 = g'(x) u'(x) - c$
which is a first-order nonlinear equation for $u'(x)$.